# Send Signed Transaction with Private key

Tags: web3js, testnets, fantom

I deployed Test Token(Copy of LQRD) on Fantom test network.
I sent signed transaction From A account To B account using A private key.
The transaction was succeeded.
But token was not transfered from A to B.

```
const nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount('A address','pending');
const Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Abi, Addresse);
const encodedABI = Contract.methods.transfer('B address', 100000).encodeABI();
var rawTransaction = {"to": 'B addresss', "gas": 100000, "nonce": nonce ,"data": encodedABI}; 
const signedTx = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTransaction, 'Private key');
console.log(signedTx.rawTransaction);
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction, function(error, hash) {
  if(!error) console.log(hash);
  else console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been great if you dropped the transaction hash.

What I can find wrong with your `rawTransaction` object is that, you are specifying a `to` key.

This isn't necessary as you encodeABI would direct the call to the right address, and that aside, to should point to the token address and not to the `B address`.

Your transfer call is likely being directed to `B address` rather than the token address.